# How to merge a @OneToMany relationship effectively?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

For example I have the following two entity classes with a one-to-many relationship:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bs;
    ...
}

public class B implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    ...
}
```

Suppose I have an instance of `A` called `a`, and `a.bs == [b1, b2, b3]`. Now I want to remove `b1` from, and add `b4` to the relationship, so that `a.bs == [b2, b3, b4]`, and `b1.a == null`.

I've tried `em.merge(a)` after doing `a.setBs(b2, b3, b4)`, but that will result in `a.bs == [b1, b2, b3, b4]`, unless I do an explicit `b1.setA(null)`. However, this can lead to complexity if `a.bs` changes a lot, and if `A` has more one-to-many relationships to other entity classes. Setting `orphanRemoval = true` is also not the solution, because I simply want to set `b1.a = null` instead of removing `b1`.

This problem has been perplexing me for quit a long time, anybody that helps me out is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can set cascade style to update on `bs` and say 
`a.bs.remove(b1);
session.update(a);`

this would do the trick.

you are telling the ORM to cascade updates on the collection, when you remove an entry from the collection, the corresponding value will be nullified.

Comment: Is there any JPA API instead of Hibernate-specific API that achieves the same? At least `EntityManager.merge` doesn't work.

Comment: the merge operation looks to see if there is a similar object in the first level cache, if found returns a merged copy of the object or adds this object to the first level cache & returns it... its does not do any cascading.